# mySQL UPDATE from PHP works partially

Tags: php, mysql

While the +1 at the **`visits`** work, the **`browser`** doesn't save any values, even I replace the

```
`$browser` = $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT];
```

with

```
`$browser` = "foobar";
```

What am I doing wrong ?

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


mysql_query("UPDATE `general` SET `visits` = `visits` + 1, `browser` = '$browser' WHERE `token` = '$cookie'");
```

Comment: You should not use mysql_* commands as they are deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use either mysqli_* or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: try to remove the ` sign when incrementing SET visits = visits + 1

Comment: columns named visits or browser don't need to be quoted, but in your first two examples you name this column `$browser`, that's completeley different.

Comment: You dont need `'` around your variable, if it is string, so try:

`mysql_query("UPDATE `general` SET `visits` = `visits` + 1, `browser` = $browser WHERE `token` = $cookie");`

Comment: Are you checking for errors? If not: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @fiction: The user agent is a string. It's got to be in single quotes (ok MySQL will accept double quotes too). But generally there's good advice of user3117036 to use prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: @VMai you dont need to quote **string variable**. If you will locate plain text in your query, you will need to quote it. But variables dont need it.

Comment: @fiction If concatenating sql statemnts (no good idea), then the result must be a valid sql statement. And string values in a sql statement have to be enclosed in single quotes. This is valid if using string literals but it is valid if using variables that contain strings too.

Comment: @fiction There's a misunderstanding. I'm talking about `UPDATE `general` SET `visits` = `visits` + 1, `browser` = '$browser'` vs. `UPDATE `general` SET `visits` = `visits` + 1, `browser` = $browser`.